# Authentication failed (Bad Credentuals) in Spring Security with hibernate for REST

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest, security, authentication

I've created a spring boot app with spring-data-rest.

My Rest API is working just fine. Then I imported the spring security. I've also done configurations after referring to a number of Web resources.

However, each time I send a request, I get Bad Credential Error  The below are my codes

### User.java

```
package com.innaun.model;

import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RestResource;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @RestResource(exported = false  )
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private boolean enabled;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, boolean enabled) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }

    public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

### UserRole.java

```
package com.innaun.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userRoleId;

    @NotNull
    private String userRole;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(String userRole, User user) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Long getUserRoleId() {
        return userRoleId;
    }

    public void setUserRoleId(Long userRoleId) {
        this.userRoleId = userRoleId;
    }

    public String getUserRole() {
        return userRole;
    }

    public void setUserRole(String userRole) {
        this.userRole = userRole;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

### UserRepository.java

```
package com.innaun.model;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByUsername(@Param("user") String user);
}
```

### UserRoleRepository.java

```
package com.innaun.model;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRole, Long> {
}
```

### AppUserDetailsService.java

```
package com.innaun.model;

import com.innaun.model.UserRepository;
import com.innaun.model.UserRole;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Service("appUserDetailsService")
public class AppUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        com.innaun.model.User user = userRepository.findByUsername(s);

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRoles());

        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.innaun.model.User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities){
                return new User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.isEnabled(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<UserRole> userRoles){
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

        for (UserRole userRole : userRoles){
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getUserRole()));
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

        return result;
    }


}
```

### ApplicationRESTSecurity.java

```
package com.innaun;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationRESTSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Qualifier("appUserDetailsService")
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

Also, I've added the below to add a test user to the database

```
package com.innaun;

import com.innaun.model.User;
import com.innaun.model.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PitchuApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PitchuApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(UserRepository userRepository) {

        return (args) -> {
            userRepository.save(new User("myuser", "mypassword", true));
        };
    }

}
```

Just as I thought, the database now has the above user and the user is enabled.

[Screenshot of the User data table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNEJ6.png)

All the other tables are blank.

However when I tried the curl

```
curl -u myuser:mypassword localhost:8080
```

it returned

```
{"timestamp":1489090315435,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/"}
```

Can anyone explain where did I went wrong.

Comment: Further to the above, I also get the WARN

    2017-03-10 01:50:05.958  WARN 18627 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.c.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder     : Encoded password does not look like BCrypt

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks fine to me. So, my best guess is that your `password` column in your database has length less than 60 which is the length of the hash `BCrypt` will produce.

Comment: Thanks, But I figured out the problem. the reason was I used an unencoded password to persist.

I still use the same config for other areas

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. And this was so simple mistake. the password I used to save a new user in the userRepository is raw instead of encrypted. I figured it out by:

```
//Create a new password encoder
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

//Encode the password
String password = "mypassword";
String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

//Create the user with the encoded password
User user = new User(myuser, hashedPassword, true);

//then persist
userRepository.save(user);
```